# Error while building the whole enchilada in openmobster

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openmobster

```
 cd ~/openmobster-read-only/cloud   mvn -DskipTests -Pbuild-all install
```

> Error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project common: Cannot create resource output directory:

Note: I am following instructions given in this link. http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/Building_OpenMobster_Ubuntu_Maven304